# How to use MultiSelectList?

Tags: c#, linq, multi-select, linqpad

I got compiling error below:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'
>
> Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'

How to fix this error?

```
void Main()
{
    SortedDictionary<int, string> items = new SortedDictionary<int, string>{{1, "apple"}, {2, "book"}, {3, "tree"}, {4, "mazagine"}, {5, "orange"}};
    MultiSelectList msl = new MultiSelectList(items, items.Select(o => o.Key), items.Select(o => o.Value), items.Where(i => i.Key == 1 || i.Key == 5)).Dump();
}
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error messages? We might be able to help you if you describe what you understand by them.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.. you're passing a collection where a `string` is expected.

Comment: Try `new MultiSelectList(items, "Key", "Value", new [] { 1, 5 })`

Comment: Sergey Berezovskiy, your answer is correct. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MultiSelectList(items, dataValueField, dataTextField, selectedValues)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470158%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) constructor expects four parameters:

- *items* collection - you are passing them correctly
- *dataValueField* `string` - here is your first error. You should pass name of value field instead of passing all values.
- *dataTextField* `string` - here is your second error. You should pass name of text field instead of passing all text values.
- *selectedValues* collection - here is your third error. You should pass values only (that is `1` and `5` in your case) instead of passing items which have selected values.

So, correct code is

```
new MultiSelectList(items, "Key", "Value", new [] { 1, 5 })
```

I suggest you to read carefully error messages, look on IntelliSense hints, and use [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us) to get information about types you are using.

Comment: This way also work.       MultiSelectList msl1 = new MultiSelectList(items, "Key", "Value", items.Select(o => o.Key).Where(o => o == 1 || o == 5)).Dump();

Comment: @Matthew yes, this is even better if it is possible that some of selected values can not present in items